# Find Contributions Search 503 error

Tags: contributions, search

I'm getting a 503 error when I use the contributions search:

.../wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Fsearch&reset=1

I've checked the following:

- Wordpress page called civicrm is present
- permalinks are set to post name
- under civi's wordpress integration settings, civicrm is set as the wordpress base page.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does it help if you try replacing `%2F` with regular forward slashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web host was running an older php version on their development server.  Updating to a newer version (they said 5+) solved the problem.

Comment: Please mark your own answer as the "accepted" one. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question on Stack Exchange sites!